# Implementing database layer in Spring / Jetspeed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nosql, portal, jetspeed2

I'm using a Spring/Jetspeed/portal architecture and want to add a new portal which uses persistent storage. The Jetspeed database itself is MySql so I'm thinking of adding some extra tables to this DB, I don't think I can re-use the existing Jetspeed tables ? I could use jdbc to then query these tables but I'd like to abstract this layer. What technologies should I use ? I like the idea of NoSql and this might be good project to introduce it in. I will be just adding approx 3 tables.